# Initializing variable. I don't know their type [java]

Tags: java, generics

```
class pair<U,V>{
U first;
V second;
public pair() {
    first = new U(); //error
    second = new V(); //error
}   
public pair(U f,V s){
    first = f;
    second = s;
}
}
```

required: class
found: type parameter

Is it possible to initialize `first`/`second` with (without-arguments) constructor of U/V type other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java does not normally allow this because of [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You can specify constructor arguments of type `Class<U>` and `Class<V>`, for which you would pass in concrete class types of the given type parameters (i.e., `Integer.class` and `String.class` for `<Integer>` and `<String>`).

It is also possible to extract the type using bytecode-level reflection, but quite complicated, and it doesn't always work in all situations. If you scroll down on [this article](http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Using_TypeTokens_to_retrieve_generic_parameters), you can find the example that makes this possible. I've pasted it below for convenience.

```
static public Type getType(final Class<?> klass, final int pos) {
    // obtain anonymous, if any, class for 'this' instance
    final Type superclass = klass.getGenericSuperclass();

    // test if an anonymous class was employed during the call
    if ( !(superclass instanceof Class) ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This instance should belong to an anonymous class");
    }

    // obtain RTTI of all generic parameters
    final Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments();

    // test if enough generic parameters were passed
    if ( pos < types.length ) {
        throw RuntimeException(String.format("Could not find generic parameter #%d because only %d parameters were passed", pos, types.length));
    }

    // return the type descriptor of the requested generic parameter
    return types[pos];
}
```

Edit: for reply to comment:

```
class pair<U,V>{
    U first;
    V second;
    public pair(Class<U> cu, Class<V> cv) {
        try {
            first = cu.newInstance();
            second = cv.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }   
    public pair(U f,V s){
        first = f;
        second = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, how can I pass into the constructor Class<U>, class<V> ?

Comment: Edited post to reflect changes to be made for the general solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope you can't, the types get erased in Java. So you should move construction to the call site.